# How do I search email with rfc822msgid:

Tags: python, gmail, imaplib

I receive an error whenever I try to search my inbox using rfc822msgid with python2 and imaplib.  The following is an example of the code I use to find a specific email...

```
"rfc822msgid:{msg_id}".format(msg_id=searchtool).replace("\n", "")
```

The variable `searchtool` is the proper message-id from the email I am looking for.  I was able to verify that by going onto google's gmail webpage and typing in the exact same command in their search box to get the email I am looking for back from the search query.  However, when I try to do this through imaplib in python2 I get this error:

```
raise self.error('%s command error: %s %s' % (name, typ, data))
imaplib.error: SEARCH command error: BAD ['Could not parse command']
```

So far I have tried putting double quotes around the whole search query and around the message-id and I still get the exact same error.  If one of you could please show me how to fix this that would be greatly appreciated. I have spent 2 days looking on google trying to figure out why I get this error, but I am hopeful that one of you may be able to help me out.

Comment: If you are writing Python code in 2019, you should definitely be targeting the supported, recommended version of the language, which is Python 3. By the original timeline, Python 2 would be dead already. It's a zombie now. Don't go near it if you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

This is a syntax supported by Gmail's web-based search, not one supported in IMAP.

The way to search by Message-Id using `imaplib` would look something like

```
typ, result = imap4obj.search(None, '(HEADER Message-ID "{}")'.format(msgid))
```

[The example in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#imap4-example) shows in some more detail how to use the results.

Comment: Note, you can use Google Search commands with their [extension](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions#extension_of_the_search_command_x-gm-raw). SEARCH X-GM-RAW “rfc822msgid:...”

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I finally got it working doing this:


 'conn.search(None, '(HEADER Message-ID "%s")' % searchtool.replace("\n", ""))'